# How To Spool Spanish Characters Using sqlplus?

Tags: sql, plsql, sqlplus, spool

I want to spool spanish characters in a text files.
The spanish characters are stored in oracle database but while spooling it interprets the spanish characters. I have changed the NLS_LANG to spanish but nothing works for me.
Please help how  can I spool the spanish characters in a text file using sqlplus

[image: NLS PARAMETERS SET]

Regards,
Anchal

Answer (score 0):

In Windows you can use "chcp" command to set codepage. So sqlplus+cmd will show and save sdtout in right encoding, if you set right NLS_LANG for oracle-client.

Comment: It is still not working ...i have the following NLS parameters set ...pfa image of parameters set...